# Is there a way to find a specific word in all files/folders in Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

I usually use `grep word *` while being in a folder which includes files that have that word.
But in this folder i also have folders which under them there are files that have that word, what is the correct command for this matter please?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a recursive option to grep:

```
grep -R word *
```

You can replace "*" with a full path to a directory that you want to look at as using a wildcard will search for the word "word" in current directory.

Comment: i feel so lame for not trying -R :( thanks dude

Answer (score 6):

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l "search-pattern"
```

or

```
grep -R "search pattern" *
```

Comment: When used right, `grep -R` can save hours.  For example, I was editing a JSP application, and needed to find the file related to a web page I was seeing.  A quick copy-and-paste of one HTML line into grep, and the related file appears in the terminal.  Not recommended for larger applications, or slow machines ;)